# binding can only be set in dependencyproperty of dependencyobject

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependencyobject

```
<Window x:Class="Kiosk.DeleteMenu.DeleteMenuWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Kiosk.DeleteMenu"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DeleteMenuWindow" Height="800" Width="800">
    <Grid>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Menus}" Width="800">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Width="800"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="250" Background="Transparent">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="250">
                            <StackPanel.InputBindings>
                                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding StackPanelClickCommands}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lb_MenuText, Path=Content}"></MouseBinding>
                            </StackPanel.InputBindings>
                            <Image Width ="150" Height="150" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both" Source="{Binding Path = MenuImagetoBS}">
                            </Image>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Silver">
                                <Label x:Name ="lb_MenuText" Content="{Binding Path = MenuText}"></Label>
                            </Border>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path = MenuKind}"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my xaml source code.
I get an error saying binding can only be set in dependency property of dependency object.
But I don't know what caused it. I don't understand why I need a way to add dependencies to my code

Nothing special, just adding to the stackpanel

```
    <Image.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding StackPanelClickCommands}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=lb_MenuText, Path=Content}"></MouseBinding>
    </Image.InputBindings>

Even if I remove it from the stack panel and apply it to the image, the error is the same


<Image Margin="757,222,312,373">
        <Image.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <!-- Default image -->
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/DefaultPoint.png"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <!-- Hover image -->
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/MapPoint.png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Resources>
        <Image.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip x:Name="USToolTip2" Width="250">
                <StackPanel Background="White" Width="250">
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=USToolTip}"><Run  Foreground="Red" Text=" : " /><Run Text=" "/><Run  Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Covid.Country}"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"><Run  Foreground="Red" Text=": "/><Run Text=" "/><Run  Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Covid.Confirmedcase}"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"><Run  Foreground="Red" Text=": "/><Run Text=" "/><Run  Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Covid.Dead}"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"><Run  Foreground="Red" Text=": "/><Run Text=" "/><Run  Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Covid.Cured}"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"><Run  Foreground="Red" Text=": "/><Run Text=" "/><Run  Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Covid.Fatality}"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"><Run  Foreground="Red" Text=": "/><Run Text=" "/><Run  Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Covid.CuredPercent}"/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"><Run  Foreground="Red" Text=": "/><Run Text=" "/><Run  Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Covid.Incidence}"/></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Image.ToolTip>
        <Image.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding MapPointCommand}" CommandParameter=""/>

        </Image.InputBindings>
```

This code I used in another project works.
I don't know why the error pops up even if I apply it to the same image element. Help

Comment: You are referring to element `lb_MenuText`  by using `ElementName`.  However you do not declare that element until *after* you try to bind to it.  That is not legal.  Any time you bind by `ElementName` the item must already have appeared in the XAML..  Odds are the the exact text of the error message has something to this effect

Comment: first of all thank you for the answer Joe.  I will listen to what you said as advice when coding. But in this case I get the same error even if I remove the CommandParamater using lb_MenuText.

Answer (score 1):

One problem here seems to be because you don't understand what a label is in wpf. You should probably be using a textblock instead.

When you bind the content property of a label to a string, what happens is the code in the label adds a textblock to it's content and sets the text property of that textblock to the string. The content becomes a textblock.

If you try binding to the content of that label then you get a TextBlock rather than the string you're expecting.

I don't follow why you decided to use elementname binding, you can just bind to the menutext property in the datacontext:

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="250" Background="Transparent">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="250">
                        <StackPanel.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" 
                                          Command="{Binding StackPanelClickCommands}"  
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding MenuText}"/>
                        </StackPanel.InputBindings>
                        <Image Width ="150" Height="150" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both" Source="{Binding Path = MenuImagetoBS}">
                        </Image>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Silver">
                            <Label x:Name ="lb_MenuText" Content="{Binding MenuText}"></Label>
                        </Border>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path = MenuKind}"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

With wpf, a button is a content control and you can put pretty much anything you like in it. Buttons are designed to handle clicks and bind to commands so are a better option than mousebinding on a stackpanel.

I tried this code out using the community mvvm toolkit:

My window

```
    <Window.DataContext>
            <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="250" Background="Transparent">
                        <Button Command="{Binding StackPanelClickCommand}"  
                                CommandParameter="{Binding MenuText}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                                        Width="250">
                                <Image Width ="150" Height="150" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both" Source="{Binding Path = MenuImagetoBS}">
                                </Image>
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Silver">
                                    <Label x:Name ="lb_MenuText" Content="{Binding MenuText}"></Label>
                                </Border>
                                <Label Content="{Binding MenuKind}"></Label>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Viewmodel for that:

```
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        [ObservableProperty]
        private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
              Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>(
              new List<ItemViewModel>{
                  new ItemViewModel{  MenuKind = "A", MenuText = "AA"},
                  new ItemViewModel {  MenuKind = "B", MenuText = "BB"},
                  new ItemViewModel {  MenuKind = "C", MenuText = "CC" }
              });
        }
    }
```

ItemViewModel

```
public partial class ItemViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string menuKind;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string menuText;
    [RelayCommand]
    private void StackPanelClick(string menutext)
    {
        // I just put a break point on the opening bracket to test this
    }
}
```

This works as expected. No errors. Put a break point in that relaycommand and it's reached when I click.

The parameter to the command is kind of pointless because the property is in the same class so it could be referenced without a problem by my command.

If I then change it back to a mousebinding on the stackpanel I can make that work as well.

I gave the stackpanel a background as I don't have your picture.

```
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Width="250" Background="Transparent">
                        <!--<Button Command="{Binding StackPanelClickCommand}"  
                                CommandParameter="{Binding MenuText}">-->
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                                        Width="250"
                                        Background="Transparent">
                        <StackPanel.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding StackPanelClickCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding MenuText}">
                                
                            </MouseBinding>
                        </StackPanel.InputBindings>
                        <Image Width ="150" Height="150" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both" Source="{Binding Path = MenuImagetoBS}">
                                </Image>
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Silver">
                                    <Label x:Name ="lb_MenuText" Content="{Binding MenuText}"></Label>
                                </Border>
                                <Label Content="{Binding MenuKind}"></Label>
                            </StackPanel>
                        <!--</Button>-->
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Not sure what else you have in that project but you've not showed us something significant here.

Comment: As you said, using elementname binding is a better way to use Menu Text property in the datacontext. thanks for the good info  But, the same problem occurs when Label is changed to TextBlock, and
The same problem occurs when elementname is changed to MenuText property. There are many comments about CommandParamater, so it is the same problem even if you try to delete it. The error message indicates that Binding cannot be set in the Command property of MouseBinding type.

Comment: I used Winform, but I am a beginner who started studying WPF. Thank you for the good knowledge about Binding and the information about Label.